# Can i use axios in js decorators?

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

Can i use axios in js decorators? I getting error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
```

with code:

```
const request = axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
  headers: {
    authorization: headers.authorization,
  },
});
```

Comment: how did you import that `axios`?

Comment: What is this decorator going to do? Generally decorators shouldn't execute async code

Answer (score 0):

```
 const axios = require('axios');   
 const request = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',{body},
      headers: {
        authorization: headers.authorization,
      },
    );
```

Comment: If `axios` is undefined when the OP tries to read the `request` property on it, then it is still going to be undefined if they try to read the `post` property instead.

Comment: const axios = require('axios'); use this

Comment: Not boys, I'm not that stupid, I didn't forget to import, I didn't mention it in the snippet. I solved the problem otherwise by moving the function to the service, well, I transferred it to axios from nestjs